# Placing a flex item under another flex item in a flex box container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want in this case `2.5` to be placed below `2` - but the flexbox container forces it to be placed along the same row, rather than place it under the div that is already at that particular order.

How do I using flexbox - place my div containing 2.5 under the div containing 2 -  **given this html**.

I was trying to accomplish this in ie using grid but where not able to do so, as grid is not fully supported in ie.. Which is why I am trying to see whether I can do this for ie only.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ewqmXw

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
}

.item-1 {
    order:1;
    background-color: rgba(200,520,266,.75);
    border-color: #b4b4b4;
    width: 50px;
}

.item-2 {
    order:2;
    background-color: rgba(145,223,0,.75);
    border-color: transparent;
    width: 50px;
}

.item-3 {
    order:3;
    background-color: rgba(145,520,0,.75);
    width: 50px;
}

.item-4 {
    order:4;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    border-color: transparent;
    width: 50px;

}

.item2half {
    order:2;
    background-color: rgb(20,100,255);
    border-color: transparent;
    width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="item-1">1</div>
  <div class="item-2">2</div>
  <div class="item2half">2.5</div>
  <div class="item-3">3</div>
  <div class="item-4">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to add `item2half` in `item-2` div

Comment: Flexbox does not allow you to stack element in a direction different from the one configured with `flex-direction`. Please explain the real purpose of what you are trying to achieve so we can provide better advice on how to approach it.

Comment: I was trying to accomplice this in ie using grid but where not able to do so, as grid is not fully supported in ie.. Which is why I am trying to see whether I can do this for ie only..

Answer (score 1):

So here's how I understand your requirements:

- item 2.5 must be underneath item 2
- can't use Grid, only flexbox
- can't alter the HTML

Here's one solution:

- Your flex items are 50px in length.
- You'll need 4 per row.
- So instead of defining the item widths in pixels, set the container to `width: 200px` and the items to `width: 25%` (of `flex-basis: 25%`)
- Now you can wrap the items. Set the container to `wrap`.
- Create a pseudo-element to serve as a sixth item.
- This item will be transparent and occupy the space under item 1.
- Use the `order` property to ensure item 2.5 is in last place.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 200px;
}

.item-1 {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  order: 1;
  background-color: rgba(200, 520, 266, 0.75);
}

.item-2 {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  order: 2;
  background-color: rgba(145, 223, 0, 0.75);
}

.item-3 {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  order: 3;
  background-color: rgba(145, 520, 0, 0.75);
}

.item-4 {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  order: 4;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.flex-container::after {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  order: 5;
  background-color: transparent;
  content: "";
}

.item2half {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  order: 6;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="item-1">1</div>
  <div class="item-2">2</div>
  <div class="item-3">3</div>
  <div class="item2half">2.5</div>
  <div class="item-4">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have add `item2half` in `item-2` div

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
}

.item-1 {
    order:1;
    background-color: rgba(200,520,266,.75);
    border-color: #b4b4b4;
    width: 50px;
}

.item-2 {
    order:2;
    background-color: rgba(145,223,0,.75);
    border-color: transparent;
    width: 50px;
}

.item-3 {
    order:3;
    background-color: rgba(145,520,0,.75);
    width: 50px;
}

.item-4 {
    order:4;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    border-color: transparent;
    width: 50px;

}

.item2half {
    order:2;
    background-color: rgb(20,100,255);
    border-color: transparent;
    width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="item-1">1</div>
  <div class="item-2">2
    <div class="item2half">2.5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-3">3</div>
  <div class="item-4">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The question says *"...given this html"*. If you can alter the html, then the solution is easy.